# Android Fragment contributes to the Action Bar when not on the screen

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar-compat

If I dynamically add a `Fragment` (using the `FragmentManager`) into a container defined in a landscape XML then switch to portrait, that dynamically injected `Fragment` still exists.  It is contributing to the `Action Bar` even though it is not visible. What is a good way / design to prevent this from happening?

I have tried using `isVisible` in `onCreateOptionsMenu` of the `Fragment` but that causes issues on some Android versions because `onCreateOptionsMenu` is called before `onCreateView` which results in `false` even if the fragment is going to be visible with the current configuration.

**Note**: I am not handling the configuration myself.  I haven't specified `configChanges` in the manifest and I am not overriding `onConfigurationChanged`.

**Activity**:

```
// inject detail fragment
Fragment detailFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.detail_container);
if(detailFragment == null)
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.detail_container, DetailFragment.newInstance(id)).commit();

// inject master fragment
if(findViewById(R.id.master_container) != null) {
    masterDetail = true;
    Fragment listFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.master_container);
    if(listFragment == null)
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.master_container, ListFragment.newInstance(position)).commit();
}
```

**Activity portrait XML**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/detail_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

**Activity landscape XML**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:baselineAligned="false">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/master_container"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/detail_container"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I am not sure why the fragment is created if it has a UI that your hiding but you could use your isShown() method in onPrepareOptionsMenu() and then in your fragments onViewCreated() method just invalidateOptionsMenu()

Comment: **"If I dynamically inject a Fragment..."** : I have no idea what that means. Also, if you change orientation of the device the `Activity` is destroyed and re-created so you have the potential to do anything in one orientation and also in the other. Post code to help explain your problem.

Comment: @LarryMcKenzie It was created when in `landscape`.  I am doing a `master-detail` when in landscape.  If I switch to `portrait` I am only displaying the `detail` fragment.  Unfortunately, the `master` fragment still exists and contributes to the `Action Bar`.

Comment: @Squonk There are two ways to include fragments, statically via `<fragment>` in XML or dynamically into a container via the `FragmentManager`.  I'm sure you know this, I was just explaining why I worded it this way.

Comment: Are you handling the configuration change yourself or allowing the system to do it?

Comment: @mattblang : Yep, I get that but the term 'inject' is something I've never seen before - we normally talk about "adding", "removing" or "replacing" Fragments. So why don't you have separate layout files for landscape and portrait then check before you add your Fragment?

Comment: @LarryMcKenzie Allowing the system to do it.

Comment: @Squonk Good point, I changed the wording.  Also I added the relevant code and XML for the `Activity`.  I do have separate layouts.

Comment: Ok so it sounds/looks like you have taken an abnormal approach to creating a master-detail activity. That is not a big deal but it is what is causing your headache. check this out: https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/templates.html#master-detail-activity

Comment: @mattblang : Show your layout files. The usual way to do this is (for example) if you have a multi-pane and single-pane layout then check for the container which is or isn't in one or the other layout file - just call `findViewById(...)` and check for a null return. If it's null, you're in single pane mode (don't add the Fragment and use a different menu) if it's not null you're good to go.

Comment: @Squonk I added the XML.  I am doing what you said, but the `Fragment` that was added when in `landscape` stays around when I switch back to `portrait`.  I believe that I read this is intended.  That is fine, I just don't want it to still contribute to the `Action Bar`.

Comment: @mattblang : Yeah, Fragment retention can be a PITA if you don't need it. Are you calling `setRetainInstance(true)` in your Fragment?

Comment: @Squonk I'm not.  And I believe the default is false right?

Comment: @mattblang : Not sure what the default is - I'm just going to check the source code now. See my answer though and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The model I'd follow based on your explanation.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    boolean mMultiPane = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FrameLayout masterContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.master_container);
        if (masterContainer != null)
            mMultiPane = true;

        ...
    }
}
```

From then on in your `Activity` you can use the `mMultiPane` variable to change the behaviour including changing how the options menu is set up (just have two different `menu.xml` files or add / remove menu items depending on which mode you're in).

Comment: So this is essentially what I am doing now.  I want to handle the options in the Fragment though if possible.